# "Или" в сложносочиненном предложении. Запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, или

Имеется такое предложение.
**Вся моя память о нём** [городе] **— как родители ссорились или как я тосковал по тебе.**

Нужна ли запятая перед "или"? Вроде бы это сложносочиненное предложение, и она нужна. Но чем дальше в правила — тем больше интересного.
Перед союзом **или** не ставится пунктуационный знак, если в сложносочиненном предложении имеется общий член предложения, вводное слово или частица.
Является ли это предложение таким случаем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Запятая не нужна,** так как два предложения, связанные союзом ИЛИ,  имеют общую третью часть (связь бессоюзная, обозначенная с помощью тире):

*Вся моя память о нём [городе] — как родители ссорились или как я тосковал по тебе.*

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

3) Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного предложения третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью: Берегов не видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива (М. Г.);